# add video upload in ckeditor5

Tags: php, laravel-blade, ckeditor5

how to add upload video for ckeditor5 in laravel?

[`https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/html5video`](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/html5video) and [`https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widget`](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widget)
I put These addons and set in ckeditor5 config.js, but still have no icon to insert html5 video.

(`assets/js/plugins/ckeditor/plugins/html5video`)
(`assets/js/plugins/ckeditor/plugins/widget`)
according to help i put this part of code in (`assets/js/plugins/ckeditor/config.js`) but have no success.:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'html5video';
    config.extraPlugins = 'widget';
};
```

code in script:

```
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    ckfinder: {
        uploadUrl: '{{route('editor.upload').'?_token='.csrf_token()}}'
    },
    language: {
        content: 'ar'
    },
})
.then( editor => {
    console.log( editor );
})
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
})
```

Comment: "_but still have no icon to insert html5 video_" Those are CKE4 plugins